# exim system filter foranyaddress condition wont work

Tags: exim, filter

i am trying to setup exim system filter, it should be skipped for certain recipients, but condition always fails:

Filter looks like:

```
# Exim filter
if foranyaddress $h_to: ( $thisaddress contains "lists.example.loc" )
    then
        finish
    elif $h_X-SIGN-ADDED: is not contains "yes"
    then
        headers add "X-SIGN-ADDED: yes"
        seen pipe "/etc/mailsystem/sign/sign.py $sender_address $recipients"
endif
```

my test.msg is

```
Message-ID: <4FE823B6.9040905@exmaple.loc>
Date: Mon, 25 Jun 2012 12:39:18 +0400
From: Hikaru <test@lists.exmaple.loc>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20120605 Thunderbird/13.0
MIME-Version: 1.0
To: <testuser@lists.exmaple.loc>
 Subject: 1
 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

 1
```

And command to run testing is:

```
exim -bF exim.filter -f sender@example.loc -bfd lists.example.loc <test.msg
```

Why it always runs pipe to script?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me, I found why it won't work: "foranyaddress" condition waits for list of addresses and won't work if there is only one recipient.
So, if "To:" header will be expanded to several addresses everything would work.